# In Wagtail streamfield template how to check if a field of a structblock inside a structblock is null?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a StructBlock like this :

```
class CardBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
header= blocks.StructBlock([
    ("text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False, help_text="Header text")),
    ("classes", blocks.CharBlock(required=False, help_text="Header css classes")),
    ],
    template="streams/card_header_block.html")

image= ImageChooserBlock(required=False)
icon= blocks.CharBlock(required=False, help_text="fontawesome classes for an icon")

title= blocks.StructBlock([
    ("text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False, help_text="Title text")),
    ("classes", blocks.CharBlock(required=False, help_text="Title css classes")),
    ],
    template="streams/card_title_block.html")

bodyHTML = blocks.RawHTMLBlock()

footer= blocks.StructBlock([
    ("text", blocks.CharBlock(required=False, help_text="Footer text")),
    ("classes", blocks.CharBlock(required=False, help_text="Footer css classes")),
    ],
    template="streams/card_footer_block.html")

class Meta:
    template = "streams/card_block.html"
    icon = "placeholder"
    label = "Card"
```

And a template like this:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
{% load wagtailimages_tags %}

{% image value.image fill-300x150 as img %}
<div class="card {% if value.classes %} {{value.classes}} {% endif %}">
    {% if value.header.text is not Null %}
        {% include_block value.header %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if value.image %}
    <img src="{{ img.url }}" alt="{{ img.alt}}" class="card-img-top" />
    {% endif %}

    <div class="card-body">
        {% if value.title %}
            {% include_block value.title%}
        {% endif %}

        {% if value.subtitle %}
            {% include_block value.subtitle%}
        {% endif %}

        <div class="card-text">{% include_block value.bodyHTML %}</div>

        {% if value.link %}
            {% include_block value.link%}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% if value.footer %}
        {% include_block value.footer%}
    {% endif%}
</div>
```

I am trying to check is a child block like Header has its value filled by the page editor or not. If not I do not show the HTML. But I am afraid the header div still shows up. Someting is wrong with the way I am putting the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blank `CharBlock` is equal to the empty string, which is not the same as null (and in any case, Python's null value is `None`, not `Null`). You can test this the same way that you've tested other empty values in your template: `{% if value.header.text %}`